# Converting a xml file into jrxml file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is there a way I can convert a *xml* file to *jrxml* file?

I am doing a project where I need to write data from the *database* in a *MS Word* file that is already designed with the required template. I have converted that document file into *xml* format.

I am using *iReport* to generate the resultant doc file. But it requires a *jrxml* file. It fails to read from *xml* file.

Comment: Why you have converted jrxml file to xml file? if you only have changed the extension of file, undo the change and save it with jrxml it will start working again

Comment: please include all relevant code

Comment: @bijilphilip Are you talking about any abstract *XML* file? Did you check you *xml* file with ***jasperreport.xsd*** file? Does its format relevant to *JR* rules?

Comment: I havent converted jrxml to xml file. I have a template in a word document. i need to get few values from the database and add it to this template file to get the output file. Now, word lets you save a word document as xml file, preserving all the formatting and layouts. I want to some how use this xml file with ireports

Comment: @bijilphilip You can not use a simple *MS Word* template for filling it with data with *JasperReports*. You can write your own application for converting *XML* in any format to valid *jrxml* or you can use *JasperReports API* or *DynamicJasper API* for generating document dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Bijil,

JRXML is a template that contains the format for the content that is shown on the report.

And from what i understand the xml is containing the input data.

How jasper reports work is, you create JASPER file by compiling the JRXML file (this can be done using iReport or through your java code). To this JASPER file you will attach a object from your java code that contain data for filling the JASPER.

[Please see this link for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936068/how-to-create-a-dynamic-report-thorough-jrxml)

**Edited:** `iReport` is a designer tool for creating `jasper reports`, I am not sure if there any tool that can convert `xml` to `jrxml`. `jrxml` will contain the syntax with respect to jasper report.

What we used to do, were try to create a similar report(by comparing the look and feel) as the one client has given using `iReport` and get the final `jrxml`. 
Compile `jrxml` in `iReport` check the look and feel with the sample word doc with the generated sample report

Then use the compiled jasper file in the application directly. The use of jasper has 2 advantages,

1. you can use unicode characters in your report
2. you reduce the overhead of compiling your code every time before generating report.

disadvantage

1. you need to keep separate track of jrxml, to fix any defect on
   previous jasper file.

Comment: The problem i am facing is that i have been provided with a template in a word doc file. I need to use this template, obtain data from a database and output it in a word doc file using a java program. So is there any i can do it? I can convert my template file into an xml file easily. But this xml file contains the layout not the input!

Answer (score 0):

Save your MS WORD file (Template) in **report directory** and using **Apache POI**,
Do necessary edits to your template. Then save your file to any place you like.

Apache POI tutorials 
[Link 01:](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_overview.htm)

To print save your edited file in temp directory and call `Desktop.getDesktop().print(file)` using desktop
[Link 02:](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.awt.Desktop)

Wish you good luck.